# `ts_rank` is returning a numeric/decimal/real that fails a "greater than" check

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

The following yields (seemingly exactly) `0.1`:

```
select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('cat'), to_tsquery('cat'));
```

Yet the following yields `t`:

```
select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('cat'), to_tsquery('cat')) > 0.1;
```

I would expect it to yield `t` if the operation was `>=`, not `>` How can I get the "real" value of the `ts_rank_cd` so that it returns `f`?

---

As background, I'm writing a full text search query that uses keyset pagination with `ts_rank`, so being able to order results based on a concrete, precise value of `ts_rank` is important. With keyset pagination, the client provides the last result from the current page as a parameter and asks for the next page. Currently, when my client passes back `0.1`, the above `>` behavior causes erroneous results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ts_rank_cd` yields a `real`. If you cast this to `double precision`, the result becomes:

```
SET extra_float_digits = 3;

SELECT ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('cat'), to_tsquery('cat'))::double precision;

     ts_rank_cd      
---------------------
 0.10000000149011612
(1 row)
```

That explains what you observe, because the `real` is cast to `double precision` if you compare it to a `double precision` number.

The solution is to explicitly cast 0.1 to `real`, so that `real` comparison is used:

```
SELECT ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('cat'), to_tsquery('cat')) = 0.1::real;

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```